# Remove white border around image every time you use the brush tool

Tags: adobe-photoshop, brush

Every time I use the brush tool in Photoshop, it puts a white border around the image. See video in [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/wacom/comments/n24yxd/white_border_in_photoshop_as_soon_as_i_start/) question (I thought it was something to do with the tablet but I replicated it my mouse).  Is there a way to disable this?

[image]

Comment: “Page not found” on the video link in the Reddit question…

Comment: Hmm just checked multiple times and I am seeing the video embedded in Reddit. Can you try again?

Comment: Nope, still not there in my phone’s browser. Clicking the _/link/[random characters]/player_ link in the post just takes me to a 404 page.

Comment: I inlined a still with award-winning graphical explanation… 'scuse the hand-drawn, can you tell I don't have my own Wacom connected just now? ;)

Comment: I can't replicate this issue.  Which graphics tablet? Which version of Photoshop? Are your graphics drivers up to date? Is your graphics tablet driver up to date?  Also note that tech support is generally off-topic here - especially for hardware, because problems like this are difficult to resolve without access to your setup. Sorry about that.

Comment: I'd say it's some sort of GPU issue. maybe try to disable it in the PS preferences to see if the issue goes away. Or use Ctrl+R to hide rulers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realize I was using an older version of Photoshop. I was using 20.0.1. Once I updated to the latest version, 22.3.1, the issue went away.